# in iTerm, how to make COMMAND act as SUPER?

Tags: emacs, terminal, org-mode, emacs24, iterm2

I'm running iTerm 2 on OSX. I'm trying to get it to run Emacs, on which I have a bunch of Super key bindings (s-a, s-f, etc).

On vanilla Emacs from emacsforosx.com, the <kbd>command</kbd> acts as Super by default. In iTerm, iTerm sees it as the <kbd>command</kbd> key. I see a way to remap it to Meta. But how do I remap it to Super?

Comment: I'll wait for someone who knows definitively to post an answer, but as far as I know there is no way to indicate Super using terminal escape sequences, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you already tried with this, right?

```
(setq mac-command-modifier 'super)
```

I can think of a possible workaround, which involves remapping keys in iTerm. Go to:

```
iTerm2 -> Preferences -> Keys
```

Hope it helps!